# 3D Objects Look Weird On Collision

Tags: 3d, blender, cinema-4d

I have about 1 month since I started using blender and right now I want to make the pacman character and for that I created 3 separate objects
"the body", Upper mouth, Lower Mouth
How can I make them go trough each other without looking weird?
[When the upper mouth interact with the body it looks weird, Logically I understand why this happens, but I don't want to decrease the size of the mouth, that it will look not that nice.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRNZb.png)

If you can provide me some information on what else can I do without decreasing the size of the mouth I would appreciate .